# wget giving me HTTP 403 in Linux EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have Linux EC2 instance when i am trying to download a file but getting 403

```
wget https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Moore- 
SR1/spring-data-releasetrain-Moore-SR1.pom
```

Above giving me me HTTP 403 error.How should i trace where its blocking me to download ?
All proxies are set properly in my Ec2.

I tried traceroute but its not give me IPs. How to troubleshoot where its blocking me to download.
I have also open all outbound traffic in security group of EC2 but no luck.

Curl in debug mode give me below

```
 $curl -v  repo.jfrog.org

 * About to connect() to proxy myproxy.xxx.com port 8080 (#0)
 *   Trying 1**.10*.**.**...
 * Connected to myproxy.xxx.com (1**.10*.**.**) port 8080 (#0)
 * Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to repo.jfrog.org:443
 > CONNECT repo.jfrog.org:443 HTTP/1.1
 > Host: repo.jfrog.org:443
 > User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
 > Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
 >
 < HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
 < Cache-Control: no-cache
 < Pragma: no-cache
 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 < Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
 < Connection: Keep-Alive
 < Content-Length: 913
 < X-RBT-SCAR: 10.1**.5.2**:1141466989:1000
 <
 * Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
 * Connection #0 to host myproxy.xxx.com left intact
 curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Comment: What do you mean by "All proxies are set properly in my Ec2"?

Comment: @jarmod i mean i have set http and https proxy in my EC2

Comment: For proxying outbound traffic? If so, presumably you have disabled it so you can test network connectivity in the absence of a proxy. Did it work?

Comment: I did not misunderstand.Are you asking me to try without proxy ?

Comment: If this is an outbound proxy, then yes I would remove it from the picture. Obviously one potential issue is the proxy itself being mis-configured so you should test without it.

Comment: Yes i tested but got the same issue